# Android Firebase database authentication fails after a while. How does one silently re-login?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have started integrating firebase database for doing syncing of SQLite data to the cloud.

Logging in works with Google identification, getting the database connection after a recent login works, and half of the time when restarting the app, all goes fine.
However, the other half of the time, when calling,

```
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
```

The sign in fails and the stack trace in the error gives the following exception trace:

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Invalid id_token in IdP response: ..., error: Id_token failed validation.]

If I log out and re-log in, then all works again. However I would like to avoid having to force the user to log out and re-log in. It seems that one should be able to get a refreshed id_token.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: The problem I described is on an emulator running Android version 28. I started another emulator running version 27 and there, the behavior has not happened yet. I will report back when I have more experience.

Comment: To update. The problem also exists outside of emulators. So the problem is still as described.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use google login, I used facebook instead. For facebook, when the app restarts, it automatically signs out, but FirebaseAuth is still logged in. So I don't think you need to call `mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)` again, `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` will give you the signed in user. The reason why you get that error might be because the google credential is probably null unless you go through the process of google sign in again.

Comment: I use Google sign in tokens for Google API features and I never have to re-login, so I don't think that is the issue. However, I've just discovered something else. See my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it correctly. There is a Google silent sign in. My code now reads something like:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
.requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
.requestEmail()
.build();
GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
Task<GoogleSignInAccount> pendingResult =
    googleSignInClient.silentSignIn();
pendingResult.addOnCompleteListener((Activity)this,(OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>)new GoogleSignInResultCallback());
```

Where GoogleSignInResultCallBack handles offering the user to sign in when failure is detected.
With this code, I have not experienced the need to sign in again yet.